# PHP - Função exec, shell_exec e system não funcionam corretamente

Tags: php, linux, shell-script, exec

Executando o exemplo da documentação no próprio site funciona.

Exemplos:

> ```
> echo exec('whoami');
>
> $output = shell_exec('ls -l');
> echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
> ```

O meu código não difere tanto dos exemplos descritos na documentação, o que desejo fazer é apenas executar uma outra aplicação com o seguinte comando:

Meu código/exemplo:

> ```
> > $comando = "python3 caminho/arquivo.py";
> > exec($comando);
> ```

E agora pessoal!?

Comment: Você quer executar um arquivo Python ou PHP? Ou você tem uma aplicação PHP que executa um arquivo Python?

Comment: Sim,  eu tenho uma aplicação rodando em PHP que irá executar um arquivo python. Pra ser mais exato a aplicação vai dar o comando de execução no terminal para executar um script python. Que no meu caso o comando é: python3 caminho/arquivo.py

Comment: Qual é o problema? Não deu pra entender muito bem. O que seria "não funcionar corretamente?". Se existe alguma mensagem de erro ou algum comportamento inesperado, edite sua pergunta e adicione mais informações

Comment: O não funciona corretamente se refere ao ponto de que para comandos como: ls, mkdir, pwd. Ele funciona, porém "python3 caminho/arquivo.py" é um comando assim como qualquer outro e ele não executa/funciona.

Comment: verifique a permissão no diretório e no arquivo que quer que o php execute